# Unable to perform operation "make branch" in replica <replica name> of vob<vobname>

Tags: clearcase-ucm, cleartool

We recently changed mastership of a stream from one site (inh) to another(ies).  Things were fine till following error.

Now a delivery from child branch to the "moved branch" results in error. Not all merges are problematic. Select directories (or I think so) are not merging.

```
  Unable to perform operation "make branch" in replica "interfaces_src_ies" of VOB "\interfaces_src".
    Master replica of branch type "project_subset_QPE-5060" is "interfaces_src.inh".
    There is no candidate version which can be checked out.
    Unable to check out "M:\dyn_project_subset\interfaces_src\src\java\src\chs\cof\project".
```

How can I fix this?  How can  I change mastership of  "branch type "project_subset_QPE-5060  to *interfaces_src.ies*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should mean, as detailed in the [IBM technote swg21142784](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21142784), that the mastership transfer was incomplete.

That can happen when there was a checked out file at the time of the transfer.
Make sure there is no checked out files (on both sites), and try and transfer the mastership *again* (even if it says it is already transferred)

Or, as described in the technote, try and create the branch on the other site, and create a synchronization packet from the mastering site using `multitool syncreplica -export` so the site where the element creation is going to happen receives the `mkbranch` operation.
You see that kind of operation in [IBM technote swg21118471](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21118471).

On Windows, [this setting can also help preventing this situation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21223822):
`cleardlg.exe`/options/Operations tab/Advanced Options:

```
When creating an element in a replicated VOB, 
make current replica the master of all newly created branches.
```

Comment: Is there a concept called "change mastership of brtype"?

Comment: @Jayan yes, there is, which is why http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21118471 suggests to make a synchronization packet to transfer that kind of mastership.

Comment: @Jayan I have edited my comment, but that same link was in the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this exact issue when trying to checkout a file to modify.

I was able to create a view, but when I tried to checkout a file it kept complaining about:

```
Error checking out '<file>'.
Unable to perform operation "make branch" in replica "<branch>" of VOB "<vob>".
Master replica of branch type "<type>" is "<X>"
Unable to check out "<file>"
```

This was fixed by changing the ClearCase Registry Server to the correct host, and then re-creating the View.